# Angular: Render child components in wrappers

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a component called `SectionedPageComponent`. It expects a bunch of `SectionComponent`s. Section components have a title and they have content, e.g.:

```html
<app-sectioned-page>
  <app-section title="Section 1">I'm section 1</app-section>
  <app-section title="Section 2">I'm section 2</app-section>
</app-sectioned-page>
```

Now I want to render the titles of these sections as a list on the left side, and the content of each of these wrapped in an element on the right.

The titles are easy: just get the children using `@ContentChildren(SectionComponent, {static: true})` and read the title property from them.

However, how do I render the contents of these children, wrapped in divs? So that the result would look something like this?

```html
<app-sectioned-page>
  <div id="left">
    <ul>
      <li>Section 1</li>
      <li>Section 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Section 1</h1>
      <app-section title="Section 1">I'm section 1</app-section>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Section 2</h1>
      <app-section title="Section 2">I'm section 2</app-section>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-sectioned-page>
```

Comment: So you need the value of `title` e.g. 'Section 1' and value of text inside tag e.g. 'I'm section 1' in component `app-sectioned-page`, right?

Comment: @Plochie exactly, and each of the sections need to be wrapped in some element

Comment: you need to only show content of tag in right div? Also after rendering `app-section` tag will be replaced by `div`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngFor` in your `SectionedPageComponent`:

```
<div id="right">
    <div class="wrapper" 
    *ngFor="let f of appSection">
        <h1>Section {{ f?.name }}</h1>
        <app-section title="Section 1">I'm section  {{ f?.name }}</app-section>        
    </div>
</div>
```